# Unable to stream audio over rtp using Gstreamer

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am using the following gstreamer command line to send audio from a QuickTime file to an port/endpoint using RTP. I can successfully send the video from the file to a port, but not the audio. I perform a tcpdump test on port 5054 and can see packets going over the wire. If I sniff 5052, I don't see packets. I can send a test signal over the wire just fine, so I suspect I am doing something wrong in my decodebin? This leads to the next question. Is there a way to analyze the workings of a gstreamer pipeline?

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
    rtpbin name=rtpbin \
    filesrc location=starwars.mov ! qtdemux name=demux \
    demux.audio_0 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! opusenc bandwidth=superwideband bitrate=96000 \
        ! rtpopuspay ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)OPUS,payload=111"  ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
    demux.video_0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency speed-preset=1 dct8x8=true quantizer=25 pass=qual \
        ! rtph264pay ! "application/x-rtp,payload=(int)103, clock-rate=(int)90000"  ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1 \
    rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=www.myurl.com port=5052 sync=true async=false \
    rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=www.myurl.com port=5053 sync=false async=false \
    rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink host=www.myurl.com port=5054 sync=true async=false \
    rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=www.myurl.com port=5055 sync=false async=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Export GST_LOG level by
`export GST_DEBUG=8`
and then include the -v option in your command like
`gst-launch-1.0 -v <REST_OF_YOUR_CODE>`